# Check the field of a related record

Tags: apex, sobject

I need to fire a Trigger when an Opportunity record is updated and Stage = Closed Won and there is a specific value in the name of the related Opportunity Product.
What's the syntax for this IF statement need to be?

Here's my class thus far:

```
public static void ConnectCustomerWin(list<Opportunity> oppList, map<id,Opportunity> oldProjectMap) {
        Set<Id> ConnectOppAccounts = new Set<Id>();
        if (oldProjectMap != null){
            for (Opportunity o : oppList) {
                //Find Oppty records where Stage = Closed won and have a Opportunity Product that starts with Connect
                if (o.StageName == 'Closed Won' && o.OpportunityLineItems__r.Product2 == 'Connect'){ //line in question
                ConnectOppAccounts.add(o.accountid);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Product2 will return an ID, you need to traverse the relationship to get at the field you are trying to evaluate

Comment: I'm having troubles with the syntax to traverse the relationship to at the "Name".  Do you know what that would be?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, a single SOQL query will not do this since the OLI (Opportunity Product) can be many records so which one would it be.

What you can do is add a roll up summary on the Opportunity for a count of OLI's with that value, then use that field in your query as a criteria.

Or you could use

```
[Select ID From Opportunity, (Select ID From OpportunityLineItems__r Where FIELD = VALUE] From Opportunity]
```

Then you could iterate over the opportunity records and check the size of the OpportunityLineItems__r. If the size of the records matches your criteria, add the ID of the opportunity to a `Set<ID>` then process the Opportunities in the `Set<ID>`

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve my issue with this. Perhaps I should clarify what I'm looking for - I need to find all Opportunities that have Stage = Closed Won and have an Opportunity Product that begins with "Connect". I'm looking for the syntax that would need to go into the If statement.  I updated the code in my original post to clarify this as well.